# ¿Cómo hacer una petición de una API sólo una vez al día y usar los valores arrojados durante todo día?

Tags: php, api, google-api

Estoy usando la API de Google Maps para mostrar mi calificación y las opiniones de mi negocio, pero los costos son enormes, a pesar de que mi API está restringida sólo para mi sitio web, tengo hasta 8000 peticiones al día. Lo que quiero conseguir es crear un archivo PHP que haga una petición de la API de Google a las 12:00 am cada día para que se actualicen y mostrar esos valores en mi sitio durante todo el día

Lo que pasa es que cada vez que alguien entra a mi sitio se hace una petición actualizada con el código que estoy utilizando y en vez de eso, quiero hacer sólo una petición por día y mostrar esos datos a todos los usuarios, pero que se actualice una vez al día la información.

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea?

Un ejemplo del código que uso es:

```
function calificacion_funcion() {
   $google_maps_url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json.bla-bla-mi-negocio";
         $google_maps_json = file_get_contents($google_maps_url);
         $google_maps_array = json_decode($google_maps_json, true);
         $rating = ($google_maps_array["result"]["rating"]);
    return $rating;
}
add_shortcode('calificacion', 'calificacion_funcion');
```

Comment: Puedes implementar una tarea programada que se ejecute una vez al día que sea la que llame a la google APi y que guarde el valor en una base de datos y cambiar tu método de arriba para que consulte esa base de datos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la forma más eficiente, sencilla y práctica que se me ocurrió al final y después de evaluar todos los métodos que encontré, fue crear una tarea programada con crontab. Esto es descargar el archivo cada 24 horas y usar ese (justo lo que quería)

Para ello, desde la terminal:

crear una carpeta donde guardo un archivo .sh (yo lo llame maps.sh y lo puse en /var/www/scripts) y dentro del archivo:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -rf /var/www/sitio.com/json/maps.json
cd /var/www/sitio.com/json/
wget -O maps.json "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?..blabla"
```

Después en la terminal ejecutar:

```
crontab -e
```

Y hasta abajo poner lo siguiente y guardarlo:

```
* 23 * * * cd /var/www/scripts ; ./maps.sh
```

Y listo!. Y ahora, en vez de usar el enlace de la API de Google, uso uno interno de mi propio sitio, es decir: https://sitio.com/json/maps.json

Cada 24 horas se actualiza automáticamente

Por si a alguien le sirve

Answer (score 1):

lo que puedes hacer es aprovechar que ya estas usando wordpress y es muy facíl, voy a tratar de explicarte todos los pasos.

1. Instala WP-Control  https://es-mx.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-crontrol/
2. Crea un evento desde el menú Herramientas->Eventos cron
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2.1 Configura el evento tomando en cuenta 2 cosas importantes: el nombre del evento y la periodicidad.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2.2 Cuando has creado el evento lo verás listado con los demás sin ambargo la "Acción" aún no está definida (o sea la función que va a ejecutar el evento).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3. En el archivo functions.php del theme instalado o usando un plugin "inyecta" este código; este código contiene la "Acción" que se va a ejecutar:

```html
//Hook con el nombre que pusiste en wp-control al crear el evento.
 add_action( 'updateMapsReviews', 'calificacion_funcion' );


function calificacion_funcion() {
     add_shortcode('calificacion', function(){
        $google_maps_url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json.bla-bla-mi-negocio";
          $google_maps_json = file_get_contents($google_maps_url);
          $google_maps_array = json_decode($google_maps_json, true);
          $rating = ($google_maps_array["result"]["rating"]);
     return $rating;
     });
}
```

3.1 Cuando guardes los cambios notarás que la acción ya ha sido osociada al evento.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y con esto terminaste(casi*), espero que te sea útil esta mini guía, ánimo, Saludos!

Para guardar el valor y reutilizarlo puedes crear una "opción" directo en la tabla wp_options utilizando add_option() para crear la opción, get_option() para recuperar el valor de dicha opción, y con update_option() puedes modificar el valor almacenado.

Si aumentas el código en la función "calificacion_funcion()" queda así:

```
function calificacion_funcion() {
 add_shortcode('calificacion', function(){
    $google_maps_url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json.bla-bla-mi-negocio";
    $google_maps_json = file_get_contents($google_maps_url);
    $google_maps_array = json_decode($google_maps_json, true);
    $rating = ($google_maps_array["result"]["rating"]);

    //para guardar el valor de $rating como una opcion 
    get_option('reviewsRating') ? //existe ya la opcion?
    update_option('reviewsRating', $rating): //si existe se actualiza el valor con update_option()
    add_option('reviewsRating', $rating); // si no existe se crea con add_option()
 
 });
```

}

Y para acceder al valor de reviewsRating desde cualquier lugar de la plantilla o del código solo usa get_option(reviewsRating).

Comment: Con esto respondes como ejecutar la llamada una vez al día. Falta almacenar lo que devuelve para recuperarlo y mostrarlo.

Comment: Ya te había votado antes. Gracias por completar la respuesta :-)

Answer (score 1):

usando el [api de cache](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_object_cache/)

```
function calificacion_funcion() {
  // pedimos al cache: nombre que le dimos al valor, grupo
  $rating = wp_cache_get('rating_from_google', 'apis');
  // si está vacío
  if ( empty($rating) ) {
    // pedimos a Google
    $google_maps_url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json.bla-bla-mi-negocio";
    $google_maps_json = file_get_contents($google_maps_url);
    $google_maps_array = json_decode($google_maps_json, true);
    $rating = ($google_maps_array["result"]["rating"]);
    // enviamos al cache:
    // nombre del valor, el valor, grupo, tiempo de expiración
    wp_cache_set('rating_from_google', $rating, 'apis', DAY_IN_SECONDS );
  }
  //retornamos valor
  return $rating;
}
add_shortcode('calificacion', 'calificacion_funcion');
```